# How to increase Faye message throughput

Tags: javascript, ruby, publish-subscribe, faye

I was wondering how it is possible to increase the rate at which Faye messages are sent. Currently I am getting messages about once every 2 seconds, but I need them every 0.25 seconds.

I have trawled through the code looking for how it is done, and tried to set `:interval` and `:retry` in the `Faye::RackAdaptor` options but I've had no luck so far.

How can I get Faye to dispatch messages to clients every 0.25 seconds?

Comment: We use Faye to push real-time messages from server to client at a rate of 0.1 seconds.  Messages are delivered over multiple channels using JSON strings and are less than 2K in size.  The service runs 24 x 7 and has been up for 10 months now without skipping a beat.  Could it be that your messages are too large?

Comment: Nah turned out to be my nginx config.  That's awesome!  I can't wait to make use of this software in other situations.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out the problem was with nginx I think buffering the proxy responses.  I changed my nginx config to this and it's all good!

```
upstream faye {
  server 127.0.0.1:63780;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location ~ /faye/(?<sections>.*)|/faye {
    proxy_pass http://faye/$sections;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Upgrade    $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_buffering    off;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_pragma $http_authorization;
    proxy_no_cache     $http_pragma $http_authorization;
  }
}
```